# Port forwarding from external providers in AWS VPC

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services

I'm looking for general feedback regarding allowing external services access to your Amazon AWS VPC. I'm mostly wondering how other people go about doing this. If you're using an external service like [DeployBot](https://deploybot.com/), or anything else that relies on accessing an instance directly (via SSH/SFTP/Websocket/whatever), what's the best option for accomplishing this?

I've come up with the following options:

- Creating an EC2 instance that has the sole purpose of performing DNAT / MASQUERADE to the backend instance.
- Creating an ELB for each backend EC2 instance, and set it to use TCP mode.

Are there any other methods of accomplishing this? With the rise of (X)aaS providers, it seems like this would be a common problem.

***EDIT: As per EEAA's comment, I'm trying to minimize the amount of elastic IP addresses used, preferring instead that VPC instances only use RFC 1918 addresses.***

Comment: Why not use a public IP with each instance, and then whitelist inbound connections to those that originate in your vendor's CIDR block?

Comment: @EEAA You typically don't do that in a VPC environment, which is now the default when you sign up for an AWS account. The EC2 Classic model of "one external IP per instance" is no longer preferred. Only your public subnets are assigned public IP addresses by default; everything else is RFC 1918 addresses.

Comment: I'm very aware of how things are done. It was just another option that you didn't mention, and there was no requirement mentioned for either a private subnet nor not associating public IPs.

Comment: @EEAA Good point, I'll update the question to be more specific

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't need to use EIP if you only need a transient public IP address. EIPs are only needed for IPs that need to stay static across different instance associations. The `--associate-public-ip-address` option of awscli or equivalent is perfect for when you don't need an EIP - it just assigns a public IP to the instance, which then goes away when the instance is terminated.

Comment: Questions that can be answered with "alternatives" are not always the best here, so I hesitate to offer an answer since there is not a "correct" one... but my toolbox is heavily loaded with HAProxy, which is some very tight code, easily running hundreds of thousands of HTTP requests per day on t2.micro and t2.nano instances. `Host` header-based request routing, built-in SSL (including client cert support), access control lists, rate limiting, tarpitting,  and even basic auth make it a bit of a no-brainer for gatewaying inbound access for HTTL or any TCP (except FTP, with its screwball design).